# Deserialize different fields names than attributes names

Tags: django, python-3.x, serialization, django-rest-framework, deserialization

I would like to deserialize input given like:

```
{
    "NameFilter": ["John", "Paul"],  # name has to be exactly 4 letters length
    "AgeFilter": [
        {
            "Min": 10,
            "Max": 12
        },
        {
            "Min": 8,
            "Max": 99
        }
    ]
}
```

To something like this:

```
{
    'name_filter': ['John', 'Paul'],
    'age_filter': ['10-12', '8-99']
}
```

In order to do that I have created 3 serializers:

```
class NameFilterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name_filter = serializers.CharField(max_length=4, validators=[MinLengthValidator(4)])

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return instance


class AgeFilter(serializers.Serializer):
    min = serializers.IntegerField()
    max = serializers.IntegerField()

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return str(instance['Min']) + '-' + str(instance['Max'])



class FilterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name_filter = NameFilterSerializer(many=True)
    age_filter = AgeFilter(many=True)

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return {
            'name_filter': data['NameFilter'],
            'age_filter': data['AgeFilter']
        }
```

It returns correct values but in case of invalid input data ("Min" is not a number or "NameFilter" contains "NameExceeding4letters") it does not raise the error. What am I missing?

Invalid data example:

````
{
    "NameFilter": ["VeryLongName", "Paul"],  # name has to be exactly 4 letters length
    "AgeFilter": [
        {
            "Min": 'I am not an int',
            "Max": 12
        },
        {
            "Min": 8,
            "Max": 99
        }
    ]
}```
````

Comment: can you add that sample invalid data?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom serializer field that renders conversion error before actually rendering the resource:

```
from django.utils import six


class ValidIntegerField(serializers.IntegerField):
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        if isinstance(data, six.text_type):
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Value should be a valid integer')

        return super().to_internal_value(data)
```

And then use it in your serializer class definition:

```
class AgeFilter(serializers.Serializer):
    min = ValidIntegerField()
    max = ValidIntegerField()

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return str(instance['Min']) + '-' + str(instance['Max'])
```

*Note*: Docs about [`six.text_type`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/utils/six/)